# slice a json array slice will not work

Tags: jquery

When i use slice to remove the first array I keep getting.

```
TypeError: data.slice is not a function
http://localhost/dev/ajax/error.html
```

My json data is as follow. I'm trying to remove "success:true

```
{"success":true,"errOne":"Message One","#errTwo":"Message Two","#errThree":"Message Three"}
```

My jQuery code

```
dataType:"json",
cache:false,
success: function(data){
$('#errors div').empty();
data.slice(1);
```

How to correct this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean the slice/splice functions, this functions works only on arrays and what you have here is a JSON object, try using the delete action:

`delete data['success']`

Comment: Amazing. Thanks. Its safe to use this, right? I read more about it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b2z052x(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: Of course, this is the right way do remove element from object